# What data type should I use for OpenGL-es vertices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

In my iOS app, I am currently using GLfloat for the vertices and GLubyte for the indices. Are these the proper data types I should be using? Every example I see on the web seems to use different ones.

Comment: I belive there are GLvector2/3/4 types (or something named similarly). You should use whatever matches the functions you're calling.

Comment: The functions just ask for unsafe pointers.

Comment: Which functions are you using? Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, GLFloat is the normal data type for OpenGL ES. The API is flexible and can use a variety of different data sizes, but GLFloat gives decent precision. The vector types the other poster mentioned are just multiple GLFloat values.

Comment: The name of the type is `GLfloat` (note lower case `f`).

Comment: I couldn't remember, and was too lazy to look it up. I'm not a case-sensitive human, so case-sensitive languages give me fits. :)